# Reposition Semantic UI React popup after height changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm having an issue with Semantic UI React's popup and some dynamic content I'm loading into it (after the popup has already appeared). Here's a little demo to hopefully illustrate the problem.

https://codesandbox.io/s/w23w7v69xl

See how the pop does not reposition and overflows off the bottom of the page after content is loaded in post popup display. The height has changed, but the position has not. How would I stop that from happening? How do I reposition the popup?

Thanks very much

Comment: I am in the same situation as you.